# Error usando @POST con @Body en interface Retrofit en Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, kotlin

Tengo un problema al usar Retrofit en un proyecto que maneja Java y Kotlin a la vez y no encuentro información al respecto, explico...

Ya tengo mi generador de servicio para Retrofit y mi interface, ambos en Java; aparte tengo mis modelos para las respuestas y envíos solo que esos están en Kotlin.
Cuando utilizo el @GET con mis modelos Kotlin no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando agrego un @POST a mi interface me da los siguientes errores en mi archivo de la interface:

```
error: <identifier> expected  
error: ’;’ expected
```

y después de esto ya no me deja compilar hasta que retiro mi @POST de la interface, esta es mi interface:

```
public interface Prueba {  
  @POST("/v1/posts")  
  public Call<MyResponse> newPackage(@Body Package package);  
}
```

este es mi modelo para Package en Kotlin:

```
data class Package(  
  @SerializedName("label") @Expose var label: String,  
  @SerializedName("name") @Expose var name: String  
) {}
```

Ya revisé la documentación de Retrofit y nada parece estar mal, no se que pueda dar esos errores y no encuentro información al respecto entonces no estoy seguro si hago algo mal o que pasa.
Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme o dar algo de luz al respecto de esto.

#### Actualización de estado

Vale, ayer seguí agregando varios PUT a mi interface y esos vaya que funcionan bien, así que intenté probar de nuevo pero cambiando mi model del Body del POST por uno similar al que tienen mis Body de los PUT, así que ahora el modelo quedó así:

```
class Package(  
  val label: String,  
  val name: String  
) {}
```

El asunto es que ahora me da el siguiente error:
    parameter name expected

no se lo que eso quiera decir y tampoco encuentro nada al respecto, cabe mencionar que sin importar que mi segundo campo se llame name o fido o foo o como sea el error no cambia, sigue diciendo lo mismo. Espero pueda solucionar esto pronto

Comment: Estas usando 2 antoaciones @Exposed y @Expose?

Comment: rayos... no me había percatado de ese @Exposed, veré si es eso y aviso

Comment: pues no, ya corregí el Exposed y sigue dándome esos errores extraños...

Comment: El error `parameter name expected` es en tiempo de complicacion o ejecución?

Comment: @Einer Santana es durante la compilación

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré resolver el problema, todo estaba en que por alguna razón Android Studio eliminaba mi import de la clase de mi Body, no entiendo por qué rayos la eliminaba pero desactivando los auto imports on fly, agregando de nuevo el import, compilando y volviendo a activar los auto imports ya no da el problema de nuevo.
Gracias a todos los que comentaron.